# Why is my System process doing disk IO?

Tags: windows, io, resource-monitor

Sometimes I want to see how much of my resources a program is actually using. But it seems that, often, even though the process is doing *a lot* it's for example hardly not doing any disk IO at all. The *System* process, on the other hand, is doing *a lot* of it.

For example in my specific case now, I have a small SFTP server which is receiving a lot of data, which I can see in the *Network* tab in *Resource Monnitor*. But in the *Disk* tabl, it's hardly doing anything at all except some small reads to `X:\$BitMap` and `X:\$Mft`. The *System* however seems to have a write speed similar to the network receive speed, and files it's accessing is the ones the SFTP server is receiving.

What's really going on here?

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the disk/FileIO: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60 and share the compressed file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system process is where the MappedPageWriter thread lives. This thread is what's responsible for writng modified pages of mapped files to the files they belong to. (It is a cousin to the ModifiedPageWriter thread, also in the System process, which does the same for modified pages that are backed by the pagefile... the ModifiedPageWriter thread is what writes to the pagefile.)

The mapped file mechanism is used by the Windows file cache, which is used by default when a program does traditional read/write access to a files. And of course if your sftp server is using mapped files rather then r/w calls for its received files, those are mapped files too.

So, this is a normal part of writing files on Windows... unless the program has opened the output file with FILE_FLAG_NOBUFFERING, which bypasses the Windows file cache (and has many disadvantages).